# paragraph inside mat-card-content is overflowing mat-card container

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I just started working with angular material but I have encountered a problem. My paragraph overflows the card but only when there is shorter text. If I use a bigger paragraph the text wraps up nice. this is the code I have

```
  <mat-card *ngFor="let s of services">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title> {{ s.title }} </mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle> ${{ s.price }} </mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <img mat-card-image [src]="s.img" alt="" />
    <mat-card-content>
      <p>{{ s.description }}</p>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
      <button mat-stroked-button color="accent">Learn more</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
  </mat-card>
```

[image: Notice how the top one with the long paragraph provided by the angular material docs wraps the text just fine but the shorter string I added doesn't. I would like it to just wrap no matter what.]

Notice how the top card with the long paragraph provided by the angular material docs wraps the text just fine but the shorter string I added doesn't. I would like it to just wrap no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`CSS`** to achieve

**`CSS FILE`**

```
.mat-card-content{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**`TS File`**

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'card-fancy-example',
  templateUrl: 'card-fancy-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['card-fancy-example.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class CardFancyExample {}
```

Working **`stackblitz`** example: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zwqlyk?file=src/app/card-fancy-example.html**